# Giving an input value to .py file? Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a .py file that has a standard input file, a variable input file and an output file.

I know created a small GUI with Tkinter.

```
    # Run A TKinter Application Script

#Create Window
window=Tk()
window["bg"] = "gray"
window.title('SPS Automation App')
window.geometry('500x250')


def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    label2 = Label(window)
    label2['text'] = 'You Uploaded: ' + str(filename)
    label2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

def run():
    os.system('python Test3.py')


Button1 = Button(window, text='Upload SPS', fg='black', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=browse_files)
Button1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

Button2 = Button(window, text='Create OBM', fg='green', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=run)
Button2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Now I want to give this 'filename' as an input to the .py file so that it knows which file to use.

Any idea how I can best do this?

Comment: Have a look at the argparse library https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Just pass the filename as a command line argument and use `sys.argv[1]` to get that filename.